# This app includes the following 32-bit only (armeabi-v7a) libraries: Oculus Dev Hub Submission Fail

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

Trying to upload a .apk to the Oculus App Lab and my Upload Failed with this error:

ERROR: Validation identified the following errors:
This app includes the following 32-bit only (armeabi-v7a) libraries: libOVRLipSync.so, libmemalign16.so, libovravatarloader.so, libmain.so, libmemalign16_cpp.so, libMonoPosixHelper.so, libovrplatformloader.so, libmono-native.so, libopenxr_loader.so, libmonobdwgc-2.0.so, libunity.so, libOVRPlugin.so, libOculusXRPlugin.so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got around this by specifically targeting the x64 architecture. In Unity I did this by Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Configuration

Change Scripting Backend to IL2CPP (Otherwise the next step is disabled)

Select ARM64 in Target Architectures

[image]

Comment: You can probably untick ARMv7, for Oculus suggests only building x64.

Comment: Unticking ARMv7 works and reduces the .apk significantly.